# Creating a popup window that persists across an ASP session

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've looked around and found a lot of tutorials on window handling with ASP and Javascript, but nothing specifically like what I want to do. Essentially, when the user logs into the site, an additional popup window comes up with some tools in it (this is what the client wants, and how I have to do it). I want to be able to constantly reference this window and push data / call methods to it, either through the ASP.NET backend Javascript directly. The user will always be navigating around the site, so I can't store a simple reference in Javascript, or it'll get wiped on page change.

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm just not thinking of. Any suggestions?

Comment: have to store some page state data somewhere...localStorage, cookies or server session

Comment: I saw something like this ages ago - it was called a "Remote Control" Javascript. This was before the .NET framework and jQuery, and the approach has fallen out of favor...if you Google it you may be able to dig up a code snippet, but I saw this on either Javascript.internet.com or Webdeveloper.com a very long time ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try.

When you use `window.open()` you have the option to name the window.  Like So:

```
var popupTools= window.open('http://toolpage', 'popupTools') ;
```

Then when the page changes you can try to access the already opened window again, by calling `window.open` but leaving the URL blank.  Like so:

```
var popupTools= window.open('', 'popupTools') ;
```

This will either reference the existing window (if still open), or open a new window and go to `about:blank`.

If you do this on every page, I believe you can access the window through the `popupTools` variable.

Comment: Progress! However I found that when calling `var popupTools= window.open('', 'popupTools');` after the window was already opened, it *seemed* to grab the right window (it didn't open a new one) but I got "access denied" on all its properties, so I couldn't actually do anything with it (like check to see if it had the right URL).

Comment: Are all the pages on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, all in the same ASP app, so they're all under `localhost`.

Comment: That's really odd.  I just tested it on my local machine and it worked.  I'm not sure why it wouldn't for you.  Would you be opposed to refreshing the popup window when the main window navigates?  That's another option.

Comment: That's probably not an option based on the functionality the popup has to have. Well, I'll keep playing around with this and see what I get.

Comment: Hmmm, this is bugging me.  Are you able to access the properties when the popup first opens?

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood—I was testing it with `google.com` in the popup since I don't have the new page coded up yet. It worked fine once I created the page.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked.  If my answer helped you, please mark it as the answer so others can find it easily.  Thanks.